# How to validate XPath using Firefox Web Developer Plugin?

Tags: firefox, xpath, firebug

Since Web Developer Plugin is an self-sufficient tool, ideally it should contain XPath checker/validator as FireBug did.

Actually I could not find it.
I am not sure that it exists. But if it is, please anybody help to navigate to.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear for the latest version of Firefox and Chrome you don't need a plugin. You can use the console and $x per comment below to validate your xpath.

Answer (score 40):

In Firefox you can use the web developer tools console for xpath validation like this:

1.Open `Web Developer` tools.

2.Click on `Console`

3.Type `$x("path")`

This should let you validate that your path is valid.

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath

Answer (score 5):

Now it is possible to use xpath directly from the browser.

1. Open Web Developer tools by pressing F12
2. In the inspector there is a search bar at the top called [Search HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIQ1K.png)
3. Enter your xpath there and type ENTER

Now the inspector should be pointing to the element that was the outcome of evaluating the xpath.
[For example after evaluating //div[@id="notify-container"] the inspector is pointing to that div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNvqt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am using AutoPager extension on Firefox. It is quite handy for generate xpath and search xpath. 
you can refer to this post for more information:
https://thachhoangautomation.wordpress.com/2017/10/11/generatesearch-cssselector-and-xpath-on-firefox-55-onward/

Comment: The blog post link is dead. In general, it's good to copy the essential information from a post into your Stack Overflow answer, instead of just linking to another article.